# Cross-Platform API Development for Windows, Linux, et al

Tags: c++, c, linux, api, window

I've been given the task of architecting a cross-platform API for our hardware sensors to make them more available to 3rd party developers. At present, we have a lot of legacy applications where the hardware layers are built in and around the GUI.

What I want to do is to remove the hardware layers and implement a solid but well designed cross-platform API which can then be given to 3rd party developers to help integrate our hardware into their platforms.

I realise that in Stack Overflow terms, this is probably a red-flag question but I'll ask it anyway.

Our existing code-bases are multi-language (C#, C++/Qt, Delphi, etc) but only run on Windows. I want to progress this further and include at least Linux into the mix with maybe some Mac/OSX support further down the line.

Looking at the bigger picture, my understanding of the task ahead is to create a "black-box" when it comes to the API. Functions such as `connect` would take in a couple of parameters and pass out some kind of device `handle` with the underlying connection code being hidden from the user. This handle can then be passed into various `control` functions in order to get the device to perform specific functions - with `callbacks` available for async notifications.

This now leads me onto my questions:

With functions such as `connect`, `read` or `write` requiring knowledge of the underlying IO sub-sytem of the operating system, is it feasible that this part of the codebase could be written as a class in C++ rather than as flat C?

So consider the following pseudo-code for a crude `device`:

```
class Device : abstract {
    bool connect(...) abstract
}

#ifdef _WIN32

class WindowsDevice : public Device {
    // Calls Windows-specific functions
    bool connect(...)
}

#elif __linux

class LinuxDevice : public Device {
    // Calls Linux-specific functions
    bool connect(...)
}

#else
#error Bad platform
#endif
```

And then the API functions...

```
Device *inst;

bool DEVICE_Connect(...) {
    // bind the device instance here
    #ifdef _WIN32
        inst = new WindowsDevice();
    #else
        inst = new LinuxDevice();
    #endif
}

bool DEVICE_Command(uint8_t cmd) {
    if (!inst)
        FAIL;

    inst->SendCommand(cmd);
}
```

or, should the implementation be a more `C` style API such as the following pseudo-code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
HANDLE *inst;
#elif __linux
void *inst;
#else
#error Bad platform
#endif


bool DEVICE_Connect(void *handle) {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        // Windows connect-to-whatever function
    #elif __linux
        // Linux connect-to-whatever function
    #else
        return FALSE;
    #endif

}

bool DEVICE_Command(uint8_t cmd) {
    if (!inst)
        FAIL;

    #ifdef _WIN32
        // Windows write command
    #elif __linux
        // Linux write command
    #else
        return FALSE;
    #endif
}
```

Basically, what I'm hoping for is some `good-practice` advice from those who have been in this situation before. Are there any merits in going with C++ for the implementation code but then exposing the C wrappers around it for the end user? Should this all be done in flat C anyway?

Final question:

The hardware devices in question have various connection options from TCP and UDP sockets through to USB HID and then simple old RS232 so the underlying functions that I need to call will be quite varied.

With this in mind, is there any real point (or benefit) in using the lowest-level of function calls - by this, I mean is there any point in aiming to use `fopen` to open a file, rather than `CreateFile` in Windows? Does this help me from a cross-platform point of view or is this just a stupid way to go, limiting my options in terms of things such as overlapped io, etc? I've probably answered my own question...

Thanks to anyone who can offer any advice, guidelines or best practices.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to inherit a `Device`. With conditional compilation, you will have only the platform-specific implementation anyways and callers don't care whether it's in windows or linux. When dealing with hardware, my personal feeling is: just use C, optionally provide C++ wrappers. But it really depends on what exactly you have to do in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Ultimately, that is the point - the callers shouldn't ever need to care, all they would have is a header file and the respective library file. They would never need to worry about what is going on behind the scenes. You're right about the `inherited` approach but it feels more maintainable from my perspective - but maybe this isn't the case. I'm more inclined towards C than C++

Comment: A C API will probably be easier to consume from other languages. Whether you implement it in C++ with a C wrapper or the other way around can be up to you, though.

Comment: I agree with @melak47, a C API is the way to go.   Unless you are going to supply the source code for the API and let the user recompile it for their target OS, the differences (naming conventions ABI etc) between compilers even on the same OS are going to make life difficult.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who works on the other side of this problem regularly (Using 3rd Party libraries to interface with hardware systems), I would encourage you to stay away from C++ for an API. Although it can seemingly offer a significant feature set, a C API is much simpler for the end user. You could even Implement the back-end in C++ and wrap it into a C API like you suggested. This approach also allows you to create wrappers for other languages like Python relatively easily if you ever wish.

The way this problem is normally achieved is by rigidly specifying an API in a simple C header that has a minimal include dependencies, optimally none. This header will specify the full functionality of your library including all functions, return codes, statuses, and data structures the user could need to use.

The back-end will then implement this behavior for each operating system. This platform dependent code ideally would compile into a static or shared library based on your need and the end user would only need to link to it. This library does not necessarily need to be open source (most of the time they are not if you are the vendor). You could distribute a the header API and Shared Object (.so), DLL, Archive (.a), or Static Library (.lib)  instead or requiring the user to compile the entire back-end.

An example of an API I have used that does this well in my opinion is...

- [Kvaser CAN-lib](http://www.kvaser.com/canlib-webhelp/canlib_8h.html)

It is not open source back-end but still provides a complete set of functionality to the end user through a C style API. I highly doubt the back-end is implemented in C but am unsure.

**Counter to what I have previously said** there are also cross platform C++ APIs. One that comes to mind is the...

- [Pleora E-Bus SDK](http://www.pleora.com/our-products/ebus-sdk)

It has a large set of C++ headers that the user can access to control *hardware*. It tries to model a complete feature set using a large number of classes the user can access, own, and control.

If I were doing this in C++, I might consider utilizing the [PIMPL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) idiom in the API to protect the end user from causing too many problems on the hardware.

Overall, the most important design practices are making the API well-defined, concise, and easy to use.

**If it is difficult to document or provide use examples, it is likely complicated to use in practice.**

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response.

I've pretty much sorted in my head that I will code a rigid C API and keep the entire library in C - I'm not seeing a massive benefit to using C++ for my implementation.

Like you say, I can then define the complete API in a single header file, with minimal additional includes (maybe a couple of standard ones like `stdint.h`, etc)

Also thank you for the links - they've given me a good insight as to how I can structure my API.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to divide your implementation into platform independent and platform depended code, i.e.

```
bool DEVICE_Command(uint8_t cmd) {
    if (!inst)
        FAIL;
   if (cmd ==1 )
      platform_cmd_1();
   else
      platform_cmd_default(cmd);

}
```

platform_cmd and platform_cmd_default will be implemented in different folders and compiled only for target platform,i.e. your folder structure may be

```
src\
  device.c
  platform_device.h
api\
  deviceapi.h
platform\
  win32\
    platform_device.c
  linux
    platform_device.c
  macos
   platform_device.c
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like this implementation and can see it working well. Thanks again